# Changing MBR code

Tags: boot, mbr

I have read that during the booting process in linux, BIOS loads MBR from the first sector of the bootable device.
Now, if I change the code  of size 446 Bytes in the first sector of the bootable device to some malicious code, or any other code, then will it get loaded as MBR? If yes, then what will happen if it gets executed? If no, why?

Comment: What will happen is the code will be executed?  We can't tell you what will happen, when code we know nothing about, is executed.  **Since an answer would basically say, it would execute the code, I can't post an answer.**

Answer (score 1):

There have been MBR viruses since the times of MSDOS. It is nowadays that maybe they are less popular.

The reasons why MBR viruses have issues:

- 446 bytes is not too big and you still need to store part of the code in files. You should be very careful about chaining your code and point to the original MBR or you'll render the computer kind of unbootable.
- Many antivirus have special code to prevent MBR modification.
- Some BIOS, specially newer computers with UEFI require digitally signed bootloader code.

Despite that I once made a custom simple MBR code to display a message and reboot, on machines which failed to boot through PXE.

Comment: Let's say normal boot sequence is more or less: BIOS -> MBR -> OS_bootloader. You can play with that but if you make a mistake or stop it your computer won't boot (until you fix your mbr again with a live cd)